# "Sticky scrolling" issue in WinRT XAML GridView control

Tags: gridview, padding, winrt-xaml, horizontal-scrolling, sticky

I have a very basic GridView control defined in a Windows Store App Page that looks like this:

```
    <GridView
        x:Name="myGridView"
        Grid.RowSpan="2"
        Padding="30,137,40,46"
        ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource myItemsViewSource}}"
        ItemTemplate="{StaticResource My500x500ItemTemplate}"
        SelectionMode="Multiple"
        IsSwipeEnabled="True"
        IsItemClickEnabled="True">

        <GridView.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <VirtualizingStackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </GridView.ItemsPanel>
        <GridView.GroupStyle>
            <GroupStyle>
                <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid Margin="1,0,0,6">
                            <Button
                            Style="{StaticResource TextPrimaryButtonStyle}">
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" Margin="3,-7,10,10" Style="{StaticResource GroupHeaderTextStyle}" />
                                    <TextBlock Text="{StaticResource ChevronGlyph}" FontFamily="Segoe UI Symbol" Margin="0,-7,0,10" Style="{StaticResource GroupHeaderTextStyle}"/>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </Button>
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                <GroupStyle.Panel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <VariableSizedWrapGrid/>
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </GroupStyle.Panel>
            </GroupStyle>
        </GridView.GroupStyle>
    </GridView>
```

At runtime, the data bound to `myItemsViewSource` appears in the `GridView` control as I would expect.

However, I am experiencing a strange scrolling issue when there are more items in the data source than can be displayed on the screen. The scrollbar seems to "resist" my effort to scroll the collection and only slightly moves the viewport, until it "breaks free" and I can scroll through the rest of the items:

[image: demonstration of problem scrolling right]

[image: demonstration of smooth scrolling beyond the sticking point]

The same thing happens on the way back, from right-to-left: scrolling happens smoothly until I get close enough to the start of the scrolled area, where it appears to "stick" again:

[image: demonstration of problem scrolling left]

Thinking that the problem had something to do with virtualization, I tried changing the `ItemsPanel` for the `GridView` to a `StackPanel` instead of a `VirtualizingStackPanel`, but this had the even worse effect of preventing any of the items from being shown. Note: the `GridView` is not hosted in any other scrolling area or canvas.

I'll post my workaround below, but I'm hoping someone has a more satisfying answer.

Comment: I got the same problem. I assume that the problem is from the miscalculated inner itemtemplate. In fact, the scrollbar is not only sticky but also resizing itself inch by inch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should remove the left margin and padding on the actual GridView and add it to the ItemsPanel declaration.  A bit confusing as the default template does have padding set on the gridview.

Here is the start of the GridView that comes with the default template with my edit to the padding on the GridView control and margin set on the VirtualizingStackPanel ItemsPanel declaration.

```
<GridView
        x:Name="itemGridView"
        AutomationProperties.AutomationId="ItemGridView"
        AutomationProperties.Name="Grouped Items"
        Grid.RowSpan="2"
        Padding="0,137,40,46"
        ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource groupedItemsViewSource}}"
        ItemTemplate="{StaticResource Standard250x250ItemTemplate}"
        SelectionMode="None"
        IsSwipeEnabled="false"
        IsItemClickEnabled="True"
        ItemClick="ItemView_ItemClick">

        <GridView.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>                        
                <VirtualizingStackPanel Margin="116,0,0,0" Orientation="Horizontal"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </GridView.ItemsPanel>
```

Comment: Thanks, this accomplished the same thing, without affecting the offset of the scrollbar.

Comment: If you can test with touch-enabled device (Win8 tablet or Lenovo ThinkPad x230t like me), scrollable region is different (scroll with mouse enables more width...?). Moreover, when user swipe `GridView` to the right-most side with touch, the `GridView` is somewhat tremor.

Answer (score 0):

Removing the `GridView.Padding` property and replacing it with `GridView.Margin` solves the "sticky scrolling" issue:

```
    <GridView
        x:Name="myGridView"
        Grid.RowSpan="2"
        Margin="30,137,40,46" <!-- replaced 'Padding' with 'Margin' -->
        ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource myItemsViewSource}}"
        ItemTemplate="{StaticResource My500x500ItemTemplate}"

        ...
```

This is puzzling to me, however, since the Visual Studio GridView project template uses Padding, not Margin.

Is anyone aware of a more satisfying solution?

Edit: removed a misleading statement.

Comment: Changing from padding to margin also moves the location of the scroll bar at the bottom. Is there away to prevent the scroll bar from moving?

Answer (score 0):

Problem is the

```
<VirtualizingStackPanel Margin="116,0,0,0" Orientation="Horizontal"/>
```

Change this to:  `<StackPanel Margin="116,0,0,0" Orientation="Horizontal"/>`

Comment: And you would lose virtualization :-).  Yes this is *a* solution, but not the solution if you want to retain perf.  The core issue is actually a known issue in the scenario which has been fixed in Windows 8.1