# WinRT GridView scrolling setup work differently on mouse/kb and touch

Tags: xaml, gridview, windows-8, windows-runtime

I'm trying to mimic the functionality of the NetFlix app, with a strip on the left that collapses on scrolling, I had to offset the tiles on the GridView a bit to the right so that they can accomodate that behavior. They seem to work alright in keyboard and scroll completely to the right (although I noticed the scrollbar suddenly grows in size when I hit the left boundaries. this totally changes when I use it on touch - I seem to have a limit on the right and the scrolling doesnt scroll past the last 100 pixels or so. how do I take care of this.

I'm assuming it is related to the bug here, but didn't seem to solve the problem with that solution there.

["Sticky scrolling" issue in WinRT XAML GridView control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13332266/sticky-scrolling-issue-in-winrt-xaml-gridview-control)

Comment: It looks like it could be related to the way the VirtualizingStackPanel is arranged in the layout style

Comment: could you solve that issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jay, I bet you solved it in the meantime. But I'll add my solution here anyway; it might save time for other fellows.

---

This effect - not being able to scroll to the very right end horizontally with touch - did go away when I either:

*) changed the `VirtualizingStackPanel` to a `StackPanel`

OR

*) Grouped the `GridView` (with VirtualizingStackPanel in the ItemsPanelTemplate) into a simple `ScrollViewer`

Hope that helps!

Comment: I'll post my answer as well.